# Getting value from textbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code. No idea why it is not working need help inspecting my code.
I'm trying to calculate the average and sum from the value input by the user. The html works well but my javascript code is somehow wrong. Help please

```js
< script >
  function calc() {
    int a = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("english").value);
    int b = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("bmelayu").value);
    int c = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("math").value);
    int d = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("geo").value);
    int e = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("hist").value);

    int sum = a + b + c + d + e;
    int average = (a + b + c + d + e) / 5;

    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = average;
  } < /script>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment3</title>
</head>
<script>
  function calc() {
    int a = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("english").value);
    int b = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("bmelayu").value);
    int c = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("math").value);
    int d = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("geo").value);
    int e = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("hist").value);

    int sum = a + b + c + d + e;
    int average = (a + b + c + d + e) / 5;

    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = average;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <form name="form1">
    English :
    <input type="number" name="english">
    <br>Bahasa Melayu :
    <input type="number" name="bmelayu">
    <br>Math :
    <input type="number" name="math">
    <br>Geography :
    <input type="number" name="geo">
    <br>History :
    <input type="number" name="hist">
    <br>
    <button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
  </form>
  <p id="sum"></p>
  <p id="average"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What results are you excepting and what do you get?

Comment: Try adding `[0]` after `document.getElementsByName("english")`.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  function calc() {
     var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("english").value);
     var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("bmelayu").value);
     var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("math").value);
     var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("geo").value);
     var e = parseInt(document.getElementById("hist").value);
      console.log(a);
    var sum = a + b + c + d + e;
    var average = (a + b + c + d + e) / 5;

    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = average;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment3</title>
</head>
<body>
    English :
    <input type="number" id="english">
    <br>Bahasa Melayu :
    <input type="number" id="bmelayu">
    <br>Math :
    <input type="number" id="math">
    <br>Geography :
    <input type="number" id="geo">
    <br>History :
    <input type="number" id="hist">
    <br>
    <button onclick="calc();">Calculate</button>
  <p id="sum"></p>
  <p id="average"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You! This work like a charm. But I don't know what "console.log(a); "for?

Comment: I was just checking the value ... i forgot to remove it :P

Comment: Oh I see, so you just fixing my "Name" and "Id" for the getElement. Silly me, Thank.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("english")[0].value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("bmelayu")[0].value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("math")[0].value);
  var d = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("geo")[0].value);
  var e = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("hist")[0].value);

  var sum = a + b + c + d + e;
  var average = (a + b + c + d + e) / 5;

  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
  document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = average;
}
```

Comment: sorry. it seems you could solve the problem but you also needed to remove `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm glad you found your answer, but I thought it might help you out if you see a different approach:

```js
function calc() {
  var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".grade-val"));
  var grades = elements.map(function(element) {
    return element.value;
  });

  var sum = grades.reduce(function(s, c) {
    return parseInt(s, 10) + parseInt(c, 10);
  });
  var average = sum / grades.length;

  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
  document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = average;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment3</title>
</head>

<body>
  English :
  <input type="number" class="grade-val" name="english">
  <br>Bahasa Melayu :
  <input type="number" class="grade-val" name="bmelayu">
  <br>Math :
  <input type="number" class="grade-val" name="math">
  <br>Geography :
  <input type="number" class="grade-val" name="geo">
  <br>History :
  <input type="number" class="grade-val" name="hist">
  <br>
  <button onclick="calc();">Calculate</button>
  <p id="sum"></p>
  <p id="average"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that I've added a class `grade-val` on each of the elements, if you simply want to add another subject to be taken into consideration you don't have to modify the code but only the markup (insert new element with the same class). Simple as that.

This is going to work on `IE8+`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your snippet - you have made a number of errors there. Now it works

```js
  function calc() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("english")[0].value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("bmelayu")[0].value);
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("math")[0].value);
    var d = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("geo")[0].value);
    var e = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("hist")[0].value);

    var sum = a + b + c + d + e;
    var average = (a + b + c + d + e) / 5;

    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = average;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment3</title>
</head>
<script>
  function calc() {
    int a = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("english")[0].value);
    int b = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("bmelayu")[0].value);
    int c = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("math")[0].value);
    int d = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("geo")[0].value);
    int e = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("hist")[0].value);

    int sum = a + b + c + d + e;
    int average = (a + b + c + d + e) / 5;

    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = average;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <form name="form1">
    English :
    <input type="number" name="english">
    <br>Bahasa Melayu :
    <input type="number" name="bmelayu">
    <br>Math :
    <input type="number" name="math">
    <br>Geography :
    <input type="number" name="geo">
    <br>History :
    <input type="number" name="hist">
    <br>
    <button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
  </form>
  <p id="sum"></p>
  <p id="average"></p>
</body>

</html>
```